# Expressing Postgresql VALUES command in SQLAlchemy ORM?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm

How to express the query

```
VALUES ('alice'), ('bob') EXCEPT ALL SELECT name FROM users;
```

(i.e. "list all names in VALUES that are not in table 'users'") in SQLAlchemy ORM? **In other words**, what should the statement 'X' below be like?

```
def check_for_existence_of_all_users_in_list(list):
    logger.debug(f"checking that each user in {list} is in the database")
    query = X(list)
```

(There is sqlalchemy.values which could be used like this:

```
  query = sa.values(sa.column('name', sa.String)).data(['alice', 'bob'])  # .???
```

but it appears that it can only be used as argument to INSERT or UPDATE.)

I am using SQLAlchemy 1.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
user_names = ['alice', 'bob']
q = values(column('name', String), name="temp_names").data([(_,) for _ in user_names])
query = select(q).except_all(select(users.c.name))  # 'users' is Table instance
```